# Angular refresh pipe on language change

Tags: angular, pipe, ngx-translate

I have a language selector and default pipes such as number or currency format according to selected language. But when I change the language (for example from en-US to fr-FR) the thousands separator does not change even though `LOCALE_ID` and `TranslateService.currentLanguage` are correctly updated. How can I solve this wihtout reloading the page?

**i18n.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import * as moment from 'moment';

import { Logger } from './logger.service';
import enUS from '../../../translations/en-US.json';
import frFR from '../../../translations/fr-FR.json';

import { languageSettings } from '@env/language-settings';

const log = new Logger('I18nService');
const languageKey = 'language';


export interface LanguageContext {
    code: string;
    label: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class I18nService {

  defaultLanguage!: string;
  supportedLanguages!: LanguageContext[];

  private langChangeSubscription!: Subscription;

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
    // Embed languages to avoid extra HTTP requests
    translateService.setTranslation('en-US', enUS);
    translateService.setTranslation('fr-FR', frFR);
  }

  /**
   * Initializes i18n for the application.
   * Loads language from local storage if present, or sets default language.
   * @param defaultLanguage The default language to use.
   * @param supportedLanguages The list of supported languages.
   */
  init() {
    this.defaultLanguage = languageSettings.defaultLanguage;
    this.supportedLanguages = languageSettings.supportedLanguages;
    this.language = '';

    // Warning: this subscription will always be alive for the app's lifetime
    this.langChangeSubscription = this.translateService.onLangChange
      .subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => { localStorage.setItem(languageKey, event.lang); });
  }

  /**
   * Cleans up language change subscription.
   */
  destroy() {
    if (this.langChangeSubscription) {
      this.langChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the current language.
   * Note: The current language is saved to the local storage.
   * If no parameter is specified, the language is loaded from local storage (if present).
   * @param language The IETF language code to set.
   */
  set language(language: string) {
    language = language || localStorage.getItem(languageKey) || this.translateService.getBrowserCultureLang();
    const supportedLanguagesCodes = this.supportedLanguages.map(lang => lang.code);
    let isSupportedLanguage = supportedLanguagesCodes.includes(language);

    // If no exact match is found, search without the region
    if (language && !isSupportedLanguage) {
      language = language.split('-')[0];
      language = supportedLanguagesCodes.find(supportedLanguage => supportedLanguage.startsWith(language)) || '';
      isSupportedLanguage = Boolean(language);
    }

    // Fallback if language is not supported
    if (!isSupportedLanguage) {
      language = this.defaultLanguage;
    }

    log.debug(`Language set to ${language}`);
    this.translateService.use(language);

    // Influde moment pipes to change language
    moment.locale(language);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the current language.
   * @return The current language code.
   */
  get language(): string {
    return this.translateService.currentLang;
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts providers**

```js
  { provide: DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE, useValue: 'USD' },
  { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: languageSettings.defaultLanguage },
  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useFactory: (i18nService: I18nService) => {             
      // Locale cant set dynamic > Change require reboot
      i18nService.init();
      return i18nService.language;
    },
    deps: [I18nService]
  }
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Done. I think thats all the relevant code.

Comment: can u make some stackblitz worked sample? i can help (use ngx-translate for more when 2 years)

Comment: @НикитаСереда After investigating and trying y realised that the best option is making custom dynamic pipes that replace the default ones. Im answering my own question with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to make custom dynamic pipes that replace the default ones. This is an example for DecimalPipe

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'number', pure: false })
export class DynamicDecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}
  transform(n: number, format?: string): string {
    const decimalPipe: DecimalPipe = new DecimalPipe(this.translateService.currentLang)
    return format ? decimalPipe.transform(n, format) : decimalPipe.transform(n)
  }
}
```